# Function parameters that signal behavior vs duplicating chunks of code?

Tags: c++, performance

I recently read Clean Code, and one concept they discouraged was passing variables that signal behavior into functions (i.e. a flag, if TRUE, do one thing, if FALSE, do another). The book says instead you should write two functions.

At the same time, duplicating chunks of code isn't ideal.

I've written a simple plaintext brute force password cracker (for a school project), which prints out each password.

I'd like a way to turn off the print portion of the code, so the user has the option of running it with printing or without (to decrease runtime).

My initial solution was like this:

```
bool bruteForce(bool printFlag)
{
    for (all letter combinations)
        if (printFlag)
            fwrite(pw, sizeof(char), sizeof(pw) - 1, stdout); 
        ...
}
```

However, if I do this it might run slower. Maybe it won't make much of a difference and I'm overthinking it?

What would best practices be in this situation? Use a flag or make a separate function with print functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many different opinion on subject like this.

My understanding from the book, is that you should avoid function with bolean parameter in such situation:

```
void module(bool enable) // Bad

// Good:
void enableModule();
void disableModule();
```

this is mostly a question of readability.

You should avoid duplicating code, in your situation, depending the rest of the structure of your class, perhaps you can have a class variable to enable / disable the flag printing as a separate function:

```
class x {
    public:
        bool bruteForce();
        void enableFlagPrinting() { m_printFlag = true; }
        void disableFlagPrinting()  { m_printFlag = false; }

    private:
        m_printFlag = false;
}
```

---

Depending the rest of your code, you can make bruteForce itself as a class with all the parameters it can have.

```
class BruteForce {
    public:
        bool start();
        void enableFlagPrinting() { m_printFlag = true; }
        void disableFlagPrinting()  { m_printFlag = false; }

private:
        m_printFlag = false;
}
```

used as

```
BruteForce bf;
bf.enableFlagPrinting();
bf.start();
```

---

*However, if I do this it might run slower. Maybe it won't make much of a difference and I'm overthinking it?*

Given it's only an additional bool comparison, this is performed very fast and I doubt it will make any significant difference compared to the rest of the code, although you could duplicate code if it is really necessary, as long as it is well encapsulated:

```
class BruteForce {
    public:
        bool start() 
        { 
            if (m_printFlag) bruteForceWithFlags();
            else bruteForceWithoutFlags();
        }
        void enableFlagPrinting() { m_printFlag = true; }
        void disableFlagPrinting()  { m_printFlag = false; }

private:
        void bruteForceWithFlags();
        void bruteForceWithoutFlags();

        m_printFlag = false;
}
```

it's a trade-off speed / maintenability, from experience I suggest you to go for the maintenability :P.

Comment: Just upvoted your answer, but there's one point I feel it's missing. The internal if on the original for wouldn't make any difference at all because the value will always be true, or always will be false and thus the branch prediction would have kicked in.

Answer (score 1):

If you are mainly concerned about performance, start reconsidering where you put your `if`:

```
bool bruteForce(bool printFlag) {
    for (all letter combinations)
        if (printFlag)
            fwrite(pw, sizeof(char), sizeof(pw) - 1, stdout);
        ...
}
```

What about this:

```
bool bruteForce(bool printFlag) {
    if(printFlag)
        for (all letter combinations)
            fwrite(pw, sizeof(char), sizeof(pw) - 1, stdout);
            ...
    else
        for (all letter combinations)
            ...
}
```

How many times is the `if` potentially evaluated now? `1` vs `#(all letter combinations)`.

This won't improve your performance so as they are acceptable, anyway.
Once you did it, if the `...` part is long, put it in a separate function band do not repeat the code. Don't care of it if it's one line.
Finally, if you want to remove the boolean flag, well, add a second function. That's not a problem at all.

Comment: That woud not have made any difference because of branch prediction as the if would not ever change, the branch would not ever change.

Comment: @TomazCanabrava Well, it depends on your target. Not all hw have (decent) predictors. That being said, I almost agree with you. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to add null-ostream discarding

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

int
main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  bool verbose = true;
  std::ostream out(0);
  if (verbose)
    out.rdbuf(std::cout.rdbuf());
  out << "hello" << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```